# What is this language?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkien-languages

This is written in the beginning of "LOTR: Fellowship of The Ring" novel. [image]

Tolkien invented many languages. But It doesn't match with any languages I have seen on internet. Can anyone tell me which language of Tolkien is it? Also can anybody give me a link to all of Tolkien's languages?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_constructed_by_J._R._R._Tolkien

Comment: It's actually English: the last part of the second line is "... as seen by the hobbits". I'm _almost_ sure there is already a question about this, but cannot find it at the moment.

Comment: (please note that the linked _question_ asks about a different writing, but the accepted _answer_ talks about this one too, as they are both in the cover page of some editions)